# Update Code first from an existing database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, poco

I have created code first classes from an existing database using entity framework Power Tools, new modifications have been applied on the database. and I want to update the current classes based on that.

Is there any way to update the classes without the need to recreate them again using the tool in order to adapt the new changes in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Once the classes have been generated by the Entity Framework Power Tools, you are free to edit them as you wish.

There is no need to re-generate them again.

Comment: I don't want to regenerate them again. I want to update them automatically. Is there any tool can help me doing that?

Comment: Why would you want to re-generate it if it has already reverse engineered the DB?

Comment: we have done lot of modifications on the database schema, and we want to reflect the changes to the code without the need to re-generate the classes, I want to update the classes based on the changes.

Comment: It sounds like you need `partial` classes for the ones that you modify and then the generation will not overwrite them

Answer (score 0):

Thought this seems like a reasonable question but IMHO I think you shouldn't do that , it breaks the philosophy of code-first approach , if you chose to develop with code-first then stick to it ,but if you opted for databse-first then all the choices(db-first , model-first and code-first) are open wide for you ,,,

but , if you insist , why don't you just pull the whole thing back again to the project using ADO.NET , here an [article](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/10/20/Reverse-Engineering-an-Existing-Database-in-your-ASPNET-MVC-Application-Using-Entity-Framework-ModelDatabase-First.aspx) that shows this.

<sub>3rasi graba ;)</sub>

Comment: Although the code in this link might answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.